# Wordpress, shortcode gets old value after refreshing the page

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, shortcode

I have the shortcode that prints latest news.

```
add_shortcode('latest_news', 'news_articles');

function news_articles($atts){

    $options = get_option('my_settings');

    var_dump(date('Y m d H:i:s', $options['last_update']));

    ob_start();

    if($options['articles'] != ''){
        include 'includes/list-shortcode.php';
    }

    $content = ob_get_clean();

    return $content;
}
```

I want latest news to be updated automatically every x minutes. So I created js file that goes in the head after jquery with action updateNews

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var data = {
        action: 'updateNews'
    };

    $.post(window.news.ajax_url, data, function (res) {}, 'json');

});
```

And the action itself in php file

```
add_action('wp_ajax_updateNews', 'updateNews_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_updateNews', 'updateNews_ajax');
function updateNews_ajax(){

    $options = get_option('my_settings');
    $time_now = time();
    $time_diff = $time_now - $options['last_update'];

    if($time_diff > $options['update']){    // $options['update'] - update after x minutes
        $articles = get_results();

        $optionsNew['last_update'] = time();
        $optionsNew['articles'] = $articles;
        $optionsNew['update'] = $options['update'];

        update_option('my_settings', $optionsNew);
    }

    echo json_encode(['res'=>'ok']);
    wp_die();
}
```

After x minutes I refresh the page and nothing is changed in the page. Only after two times refresh button is clicked, the information is updated in the page. After one refresh, it seams that the information is updated in db but the shortcode is still working with old values.

Comment: can you paste the code of get_results() ?

Comment: $options['last_update'] isn't changed. I am tracking it now. That functions doesn't matter in this step.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
update_option('my_settings', $optionsNew);
```

As there is typeo mistale in your code.

Comment: I fixed this. The problem is still somewhere else. As I understand wp_head updates information and shortcode takes old.

Comment: I deleted everything related to ajax and copied pasted almost everything from updateNews_ajax function to shortcode function instead of this line: $options = get_option('my_settings'); and everything works fine.